# Simple Qt code for network simplistic network connection

Tags: qt, tcp

I'm completely new at using the QtNetwork for connecting computers.

Right now all I want is to see an attempt at a connection. So I create a GUI application and on the mainwindow.cpp I write these two functions as slots for two buttons:

```
void MainWindow::on_pbTalk_clicked(){
    QString IP = ui->leIP->text();
    ui->pteLog->appendPlainText("Now Talking to IP: " + IP);
    talker = new Talker();
    talker->connectToHost(IP,25000);
}

void MainWindow::on_pbListen_clicked(){
    ui->pteLog->appendPlainText("Now listening on any port, I think");
    listener = new Listener(this);
    if (!connect(listener, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(on_newConnections()))){
        ui->pteLog->appendPlainText("The connection of slot and signal failed!");
    }
}
```

Now Talker is essentially a QTcpSocket there is nothing reimplemented just yet.

Listener is a QTcpServer with the following code con Listener.cpp:

```
Listener::Listener(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{

    qDebug() << "Listening on any port";
    listen(QHostAddress::Any);

}

void Listener::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor){
    qDebug() << "New connection: " << socketDescriptor;
}
```

So I run two instances of the same program. One is in my machine. I run the program and push the Listen button (IP 10.255.255.101).

The second instance is run in a virtual machine (IP 10.255.255.215) where I run the program and push the Talk button. This, as I understand should attempt to open a connection to IP (which is 10.255.255.101) at port 25000 and I should get a "New connection" message in the console. However no such message appears. And since this is not working, I'm not moving on.

Can any one tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documenation of [`QTcpServer::listen`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#listen) - it says:

> Tells the server to listen for incoming connections on address address
>   and port port. If port is 0, a port is chosen automatically. If
>   address is QHostAddress::Any, the server will listen on all network
>   interfaces.

`QHostAddress::Any` means that you are listening on all network interfaces, not ports. (For example, if you want to have a local server only, you could use `QHostAddress::LocalHost` - check [QHostAddress::SpecialAddress](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostaddress.html#SpecialAddress-enum) for more like that.

If you want to set the port manually, you have to call:

```
listen(QHostAddress::Any, 25000);
```

If not, you can get the automatically chosen port by calling

```
quint16 port = serverPort();
```

Comment: The message (text that I wrote on console) was wrong and didn't realize. And since I was following an example that did not use port.... The mistake. It worked now. My bad for not reading the documentation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The "listening on any port" idiom isn't available for your use; it's not how UDP and TCP were meant to be used. Most likely you shouldn't be designing your communications that way. Use a dedicated port.

If you want to build a packet sniffer, you'll have to use the platform-specific mechanisms designed for that. There are libraries that help you with that task, the most notable would be [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org) on Windows and cross-platform [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org) from the TcpDump project.